# call function to highlight code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-highlighting

Please see the the following http://valogiannis.com/recent/ .I have a webpage and when user click XHTML code a div with id result loads the contents of a webpage (in this case codes/advocasys.html). In fact what I wish to do is to highlight the html code. I have link the necessary css/js. I use the [SyntaxHighlighter  3.0.83](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). This highlighter needs to call the `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` after the `<pre>` tag (more info [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html)). If I have the html code in the same page which I want to highlight works nice, but I cannot make it to work, when the script loads the external page advocasys.html. I tried to put the

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>
```

in the bottom of the advocasys.html, but It didn't work. How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.all()` call attaches an event handler to `window.load` which already happened, instead use `.highlight()`, like this:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call SyntaxHiglighter in the callback function after the data is returned:

> ```
> $('#myLink').click(function(){
>    $('#result').load('codes/advocasys.html', function() {
>        $('#result').show();
>        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); 
>        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
>    });
>
>    return false;
> ```
>
> });

Comment: This way works as well, but the issue isn't the place the OP is calling it, it's the ineffectiveness of the `.all()` function after `window.onload` :)